# Arduino algorithm - Compass direction

Tags: arduino

I've been working on a hobby project, and I need your help now! I'm using Arduino with a Uno board. My project is a moving vehicle, 4 wheels. I have a compass, that reads a x= 0-360. However, I want to be able to write "Kurs:" 0-360, and the vehicle will rotate so the vehicles' front is faced at that compass direction. I also want it to take the shortest way to that dorection. How can I write a algorithm in Arduino to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you can read the compass and have the desired heading in mind, the pseudo-code is as simple as:

```
# Start by defaulting to left rotation.

direction = left
rotation = readCompass() - desiredHeading

# Handle case where current heading was _less_ than desired heading.

if rotation < 0:
    rotation = rotation + 360

if rotation > 180:
    direction = right
    rotation = 360 -rotation

# Now rotate <rotation> degrees in <direction> direction
```